# Why are my Magento Model and Helper overrides not being run?

Tags: magento-1.9, model, override-model

I'm trying to override the **core** Magento class **Mage_Payment_Model_Info** in order to solve an **error**.

To be clear, the override I am talking about has been entirely written by me, and is extending a core Magento model class.  The override is not showing up in the stack trace generated by the error, the core version is. A list of solutions I have tried so far is as follows. None have been fully successful.

- Successfully able to override a block that is also part of this process and that override appears in the stack trace.
- Checked for any conflicts.  I found some but when I changed my override extends so it extends from the potential conflict class it has no effect.
- Made the code in my override very similar to the original so I know it is not a result of the code I have changed.
- Added log statements to both my override and the original so I can confirm which version is being run.
  The code for the override is as follows:

  ```
  class Work_Rewrites_Model_Payment_Info extends Mage_Payment_Model_Info {
      public function getMethodInstance()
      {
          Mage::log("In rewrite payment info model");
          if (!$this->hasMethodInstance()) {
              if ($this->getMethod()) {
                  $instance = Mage::helper('payment')->getMethodInstance($this->getMethod());
                  if ($instance) {
                      $instance->setInfoInstance($this);
                      $this->setMethodInstance($instance);
                      return $instance;
                  }
              }
              //return false;
              Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('payment')->__('The requested Payment Method is not available.'));
          }

          return $this->_getData('method_instance');
      }
  }
  ```

Revlevant code from the config file is as follows:

```
    <config>
        <global>
            <models>
                <rewrites>
                    <class>Work_Rewrites_Model</class>
                </rewrites>
                <payment>
                    <rewrite>
                        <info>Work_Rewrites_Model_Payment_Info</info>
                    </rewrite>
                </payment>
            <models>
        <global>
    <config>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 <config>
        <global>
            <models>
                <payment>
                    <rewrite>                       
                   <payment_info>Work_Rewrites_Model_Payment_Info</payment_info>
                    </rewrite>
                </payment>
            <models>
        <global>
    <config>
```

Comment: Just tried it.  It did not work

Comment: try to log your text in this format. `Mage::log('text here', null, 'system.log', true);`

Comment: Which file should I put that code in?

Comment: the one you override ` Work_Rewrites_Model_Payment_Info` and mention log there

Comment: Once I add and try to run that what should that reveal?

Comment: you have to check system.log file for your text. If your text is in there that means your file has been override

Comment: I had already done that before submitting this question.  I know for a fact and via several different methods that my override file is not being called.